# Why is Pandas df.nunique() and DAX DISTINCTCOUNT() returning different results on the same dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset I need to create a dashboard from in Powerbi.
I created said dataset from cleaning in Pandas and exported to CSV.
I am visualizing a card for unique values in a column and when I run `df['col'].nunique()` I get 1765, but when I run `DISTINCTCOUNT('col')` on the same dataset in PowerBi I get 1746.

The total number of rows is exactly the same across both Python and PowerBi at 2843 but the unique counts aren't.

I have tried using all the variations of DISTINCTCOUNT in PowerBi but to no avail.
I have also tried `df.nunique(dropna = False)` and also no luck either. There's still discrepancy in the two figures.

Sample Dataset:

| company | sector | amount | founded | investor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC Co. | Fintech | 1000 | 2018 | XYG investor |
| DEF Co. | Edtech | 1250 | 2012 | GYT investor |
| GHi Co. | Saas | 23456 | 1980 | Byth investor |

If I run `df.nunique('investor')` I get `1765` in pandas

But pulling the same dataset to PowerBI and running `DISTINCTCOUNT(investor)` I get `1746`.

Also, it's not just that one column, even the company column `df['company'].nunique()` returns `2204` but in PowerBI `DISTINCTCOUNT(company)` returns `2143`

Comment: please provide your code as well as your input data

Comment: [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How do I upload the csv @MrIrrelevant

Comment: You could copy paste a few lines as an example

Comment: @The_Monarch Read: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @The_Monarch is more to data validation; I would recommend validating each row. Get the data in Excel and pivot it to see the duplicate, do the same in power BI. There could be multiple reason to it. It's not coding issue. Its data Issue.